# Re-arrange JSON file (using adjacency matrix)

Tags: json, csv, d3.js, matrix, transform

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "country": "Greece",
    "names": [
      "Alex",
      "Betty",
      "Catherine",
      "Dave",
      "Edward",
      "Frank",
      "George",
      "Helen",
      "Irene"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": "US",
    "names": [
      "John",
      "Alex",
      "Edward",
      "Kate",
      "Robert",
      "Irene",
      "Tim",
      "Sam"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "country": "France",
    "names": [
      "Helen",
      "Kate",
      "Louise",
      "Tim",
      "Catherine",
      "Arthur",
      "Frank",
      "Natalie",
      "Dave"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "country": "India",
    "names": [
      "Ritesh",
      "Alex",
      "Betty",
      "Robert"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "country": "India",
    "names": [
      "Nafeez",
      "Tom",
      "Natalie",
      "Gunar",
      "Louise",
      "Arthur"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want it to be "name centered" and look like this:

```
{
"groups": [     
    {
    "gr_id":1
    "name":"Alex",
    "country":"Greece"
    },
    .........
    {
    "gr_id":1
    "name":"Irene",
    "country":"Greece"
    },


    {
    "gr_id":2
    "name":"John",
    "country":"US"
    ..........  
    {
    "gr_id":2
    "name":"Sam",
    "country":"US"
    },


    {
    "gr_id":3
    "name":"Helen",
    "country":"France"
    },
    .........
    {
    "gr_id":3
    "name":"Dave",
    "country":"France"
    },


    {
    "gr_id":4
    "name":"Ritesh",
    "country":"India"
    },
    ........
    {
    "gr_id":4
    "name":"Robert",
    "country":"India"
    },

    {   
    "gr_id":5
    "name":"Nafeez",
    "country":"India"
    },
    ...........
    {
    "gr_id":5
    "name":"Arthur",
    "country":"India"
    }
        ],
"links": [      
    {
    "source":"Alex"
    "target":"Irene",
    "count":1
    "country":"Greece"
    },
    ...
    {
    "source":"Alex"
    "target":"Arthur",
    "count":0
    "country":"India"
    },
    ... 
        ]   
}
```

For `count` in `Links` I have an adjacency matrix for each country/name (csv format) like this :[screenshot of csv file (ad. matrix for India)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY3YH.png)

This json is just an example. I have much bigger file (I need it for D3 graph visualization)

Comment: I end up using this : graph = graph_r.nodes.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
    acc.concat(
      curr.name.map(item => ({
        gr_id: curr.id,
        country: curr.country,
        name: item
      }))
    ),
  []
);

Answer (score 1):

`Reduce()` and `map()` work perfectly for this. This basically takes each item and then maps over the names, appending the results of `map()` to an array:

```
let obj = {}
obj.groups = json.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr.names.map(
    item => ({gr_id: curr.id, country: curr.country, name: item})
    )), [])

console.log(obj)

//  { groups:
//    [ { gr_id: 1, country: 'Greece', name: 'Alex' },
//      { gr_id: 1, country: 'Greece', name: 'Betty' },
//       ...etc
//     ]
//  }
```